# Opening a modal from another modal throw error

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, materialize

I am using **Materizalize CSS** with **Jquery** and I get the following **error** when I open **a modal from another modal**: `

> materialize.min.js:6 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded.

What's wrong with that and how to fix it?

This is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal').modal();
});
```

and so all modals have the class .modal

Here is the example:

```
<!--Signup Modal Structure -->
                <div id="signup_modal" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <a href="#!" class="col s6 modal-action modal-close">
                                <i class="fa fa-times-circle-thin fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <a class="col s12 waves-effect waves-light btn-large social facebook">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign up with facebook</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <a class="col s12 waves-effect waves-light btn-large social google">
                                <i class="fa fa-google"></i> Sign up with google</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="col s12 separator">
                                or
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <a class="col s12 waves-effect waves-light btn-large social lime  modal-action modal-close modal-trigger" href="#signupEmail_modal">
                                <i class="small material-icons">email</i>Sign up with email</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12 modal-footer">
                                <span class="col s9">Already have a LimeLINE account?</span>
                                <a href="#!" class="col s3">Login</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: probably the same problem as in https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5828